# Remove the last empty line from each text file

Tags: python

I have many text files, and each of them has a empty line at the end. My scripts did not seem to remove them. Can anyone help please?

```
# python 2.7
import os
import sys
import re

filedir = 'F:/WF/'
dir = os.listdir(filedir)

for filename in dir:
    if 'ABC' in filename: 
        filepath = os.path.join(filedir,filename)
        all_file = open(filepath,'r')
        lines = all_file.readlines()
        output = 'F:/WF/new/' + filename

        # Read in each row and parse out components
        for line in lines:
            # Weed out blank lines
            line = filter(lambda x: not x.isspace(), lines)

            # Write to the new directory 
            f = open(output,'w')
            f.writelines(line)
            f.close()
```

Comment: One note: you reassign to the `dir` namespace `os.listdir(filedir)`. That means you're writing over the built-in `dir` function, which is not recommended. Although it's not affecting your output, this is somewhat of a "style" consideration.

Comment: Good point! Will try to improve the code later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove last empty line by using:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    with open(output, 'w') as w:
        w.write(data[:-1])
```

Comment: Won't this solution remove the last line even if not empty?

Comment: Its removing the last character of the file which is `\n`, OP mentioned that its there in all of his files. And even if not, worst case is the last `\n` character of the last line will be removed instead of the extra one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Python's [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) function to do this as follows:

```
filename = "test.txt"

with open(filename) as f_input:
    data = f_input.read().rstrip('\n')

with open(filename, 'w') as f_output:    
    f_output.write(data)
```

This will remove all empty lines from the end of the file. It will not change the file if there are no empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without using the re module:

```
filedir = 'F:/WF/'
dir = os.listdir(filedir)

for filename in dir:
    if 'ABC' in filename: 
        filepath = os.path.join(filedir,filename)

        f = open(filepath).readlines()
        new_file = open(filepath, 'w')
        new_file.write('')
        for i in f[:-1]:

           new_file.write(i)

       new_file.close()
```

For each filepath, the code opens the file, reads in its contents line by line, then writes over the file, and lastly writes the contents of f to the file, except for the last element in f, which is the empty line.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But for some reason those empty lines are still there...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last blank line by the following command. This worked for me:

```
file = open(file_path_src,'r')
lines = file.read()
with open(file_path_dst,'w') as f:
    for indx, line in enumerate(lines):    
       f.write(line)
       if indx != len(lines) - 1:
          f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work fine

```
new_file.write(f[:-1])
```